# Filtering ui grid by using filter_url_params, making filters visible

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-grid

I need to pre-filter a UI component grid based on parameters passed by url so I'm using the filter_url_params in the xml definition of the UI component.
It's working great, but when you put a parameter in the url, it doesn't display the filter being applied in the list of "Active filters". This is a bit confusing/misleading. How can I display the filter applied by url in the list of Active filters?
I've (unsuccessfully) tried modifying the bookmark like:

`$config['current']['filters']["applied"] = ["FILTER_APPLIED" => $searchTerm];`

I also tried the quick and dirty way to set the filter in the request like:

`$this->request->setParams(['filters' => ["FILTER_APPLIED" => $search]]);`

None of that worked unfortunately, and I'm running out of ideas, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks